# EventGrid-triggered Python Azure Function "ClientOtherError" and "AuthorizationError", how to troubleshoot?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

For some reason, today my Python Azure Function is not firing.

**Setup:**

- Trigger: Blob upload to storage account
- Method: EventGrid
- Auth: Uses System-assigned Managed Identity to auth to Storage Account
- Advanced Filters:

  - Subject ends with .csv, .json
  - data.api contains "FlushWithClose"

**Issue:**

- Upload a .csv file
- No EventGrid triggered
- New "ClientOtherError" and "AuthorizationError"s shown in logs
  [image]

**Question:**

These are NEW errors and this is NEW behavior of an otherwise working Function. No changes have been recently made.

- What do these errors mean?
- How do I troubleshoot them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Function failures occurring, which App Insights Alert to create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635640/azure-function-failures-occurring-which-app-insights-alert-to-create)

Comment: Thats my post too. It focuses on `What are these new errors?
How do I create an App Insight alert that catches them?` This post focuses on `What do these errors mean? How do I troubleshoot them?`

Answer (score 0):

The way I troubleshot the Function was to:

1. Remove ALL ADVANCED FILTERS from the EventGrid trigger
2. Attempt upload
3. Upload successful
4. Look at EventGrid message
5. The culprit (though unclear why `ClientOtherError` and `AuthorizationError` are generated here!) seems to be:

- Files pushed to Azure Storage via Azure Data Factory use the `FlushWithClose` api.
- These are the only ones I want to grab
- Our automations all use ADF and if you don't have the `FlushWithClose` filter in place, your Functions will run 2x (because ADF causes two events on the storage but only one (flush with close) is the actual blob write.)

```
{
    "id": "redact",
    "data": {
        "api": "FlushWithClose",
        "requestId": "redact",
        "eTag": "redact",
        "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
        "contentLength": 87731520,
        "contentOffset": 0,
        "blobType": "BlockBlob",
        "blobUrl": "https://mything.blob.core.windows.net/mything/20201209/yep.csv",
        "url": "https://mything.dfs.core.windows.net/mything/20201209/yep.csv",
        "sequencer": "0000000000000000000000000000701b0000000000008177",
        "identity": "redact",
        "storageDiagnostics": {
            "batchId": "redact"
        }
    },
    "topic": "/subscriptions/redact/resourceGroups/redact/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/redact",
    "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/mything/blobs/20201209/yep.csv",
    "event_type": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
}
```

- Files pushed to Azure Storage via Azure Storage Explorer (and via Azure Portal) use the `PutBlob` api.

```
{
    "id": "redact",
    "data": {
        "api": "PutBlob",
        "clientRequestId": "redact",
        "requestId": "redact",
        "eTag": "redact",
        "contentType": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "contentLength": 1889042,
        "blobType": "BlockBlob",
        "blobUrl": "https://mything.blob.core.windows.net/thing/yep.csv",
        "url": "https://mything.blob.core.windows.net/thing/yep.csv",
        "sequencer": "0000000000000000000000000000761d0000000000000b6e",
        "storageDiagnostics": {
            "batchId": "redact"
        }
    },
    "topic": "/subscriptions/redact/resourceGroups/redact/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/redact",
    "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/thing/blobs/yep.csv",
    "event_type": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
}
```

- I was testing locally with ASE instead of using our ADF automations
- Thus the advanced filter for `data.api` was not triggering the EventGrid

Ok... but what about the errors?