# Azure Function failures occurring, which App Insights Alert to create?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Eh! Troubleshooting this all morning to no avail.

**Background:**

- What: Azure Function
- Runtime: Python
- **Trigger**: EventGrid w/ Advanced Filters
- Advanced Filters (NOTE: Working just fine for last 30+ days):
  [image]
- Subscribed to: Storage Account; blob upload only
- Auth: System-assigned Managed Identity (Function SAMI added as `BlobDataReader` role to Storage Account)

**Issue:**

- Uploading .csv files to blob container does not trigger the Function
- AND various "ClientOtherError" and "AuthenticationError" messages are shown in "Request Breakdown" blade

[image]
[image]

**Questions:**

1. What are these new errors?
2. How do I create an App Insight alert that catches them?

Comment: Only context in which I've seen `ClientOtherError` is when Azure Synapse was trying to read a 20KB file "efficiently" by assuming it's 4MB and then issuing 8 parallel REST API calls to read 8 chunks of 0.5 MB each (0-0.5MB, 0.5-1MB, 1MB-1.5MB, ..., 3.5-4MB). All calls except first one failed with HTTP-416, which is `ClientOtherError`.

Comment: Without more info there isn't much anyone can help you with. Is it Trigger or Input binding? What is the filter set to? Example of path where you're placing csv file etc. One way to get additional info is to enable [storage diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging?tabs=dotnet). I use Portal to enable it `Diagnostic settings (classic)` -> `Logging` section. It would give you an insight on all operations on your storage account.

Comment: Updated OP. Trigger; Advanced Filters shown.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple to create an application insights alert for an azure function error.

You should know that all the errors will flow into the `exceptions table` in application insights. When create an alert, you should choose the `custom log search` as signal. next, you can write a query to query the errors from `exceptions table`.